# Monitoring Active Directory events

Tags: c++, mfc, active-directory, visual-c++, observer-pattern

How can I programatically detect any changes that occur to Microsoft's Active Directory?

Comment: how is this question related to the tags? APIs are language-independent and therefure IDE independent. MFC does not have APIs for AD.

Answer (score 2):

You could enable auditing of directory service changes, than write a script or application to query the security log for the appropriate events.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to be a bit more specific.  Do you want to detect changes to one or two objects?  If so, @DSO's recommendation is a good one.  If you want to be able to do regular imports of all changes [DirSync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677626(VS.85).aspx) is probably what you need.